# Create Amazon RDS instance from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to do something very simple, I want to take a snapshot of a RDS instance (OK!) , and restore it on another instance but with a different size (duh!). 
If I restore the snapshot It doesn't allow me to choose the capacity of the new instance.
If I create a DB instance, I dont know how to "attach" the snapshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDS is a bit different. If you want to reduce the size of the volume, you need to export and reimport your data. When working from a snapshot, you have to choose the same volume size.